# Android Dagger 2 keep fragment alive as long as activity

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I have activity with bottom bar, that switches two fragments `galleryFrament` and `profilefragment`, that are injected into `MainActivity`:

```
class MainActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity(), MainContract.View {

@Inject
lateinit var galleryFragment: GalleryFragment

@Inject
lateinit var profileFragment: ProfileFragment
```

I switch between them in this way:

```
val transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
transaction.replace(frameId, fragment)
transaction.commit()
```

Module that provides `MainActivity`, with Scope `@ActivityScoped`:

```
  @Module
  abstract class ActivityBindingModule {

    @ActivityScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = arrayOf(MainModule::class, GalleryModule::class, ProfileModule::class))
    internal abstract fun mainActivity(): MainActivity
```

Module that provides `GalleryFragment`:

```
  @Module
internal abstract class GalleryModule {

    @FragmentScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun galleryFragment(): GalleryFragment

    @ActivityScoped
    @Binds
    abstract fun galleryPresenter(galleryPresenter: GalleryPresenter): GalleryContract.Presenter


    @Module
    companion object {
        @ActivityScoped
        @Provides
        @JvmStatic
        fun galleryAdapter(context: Context): GalleryAdapter {
            return GalleryAdapter(context);
        }
    }
}
```

And, finaly `AppComponent`:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(ImagesRepositoryModule::class,
        ApplicationModule::class,
        ActivityBindingModule::class,
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
        EventsModule::class))
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<MyApplication> {
```

`GalleryFragment` is provided with `@FragmentScoped` annotation from `GaleryModule`. I took aproach with annotatins `@FragmentScoped` and `@ActivityScoped` from google blueprints samples posted here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture][google-archutecture

**The probem is:** When I switch fragments, the new instance of `GalleryFrament` is created (`onCreate()` called every time), but I want to use previously created instance of it. 
As I understand dagger scopes, `GalleryFragment` should be `@ActivityScoped`(to keep it alive as long as activity lives), but if I set it, `@ContributesAndroidInjector` produces Subcomponent with the same scope as its parent, and that is illegal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have your fragment in your activity scope you mustn't create fragment subcomponent with `@ContributesAndroidInjector` so instead of

```
@FragmentScoped
@ContributesAndroidInjector
abstract fun galleryFragment(): GalleryFragment
```

try to move it in your companion like so

```
@Provides
@ActivityScoped
@JvmStatic
fun galleryFragment(): GalleryFragment = GalleryFragment.newInstance()
```

or remove it and from your GalleryFragment class

```
@ActivityScope
class GalleryFragment 
@Inject
constructor() : Fragment()
```

Though i wouldn't recommanded to do so, why would you want to have fragments matching your activity lifecycle?

Comment: I want to keep its state, and I dont want to create adapter every time i select this fragment in bottom bar (GalleryFragment contains RecyclerView). I think, it would be better, if only onCreateView, and onDestroyView would be called when I switch fragments, but not onCreate and onDestroy. Or am i going wrong? Maybe it is better to keep ALL state in fragment presenter, and restore new fragment instance based on it?

Comment: If you want to keep some data around you may use your activity viewmodel/presenter to store it, but avoid keeping all fragment instance in memory

Comment: Thanks for the response.
In my case I`m using three presenters on this screen:
MainPresenter (for actvity), GalleryPresenter and ProfilePresenter (for both of switched fragments). GalleryPresenter marked as @ActivityScoped, so, as I understand it will live as long as activity lives. So, can I store state in it? Or is it a better aproach to store state in activty presenter?